# cin and cout in c programming

Tags: c++, c

My code is written in c. However, I converted the code via changing the header files to c++ and the program works fine. Now my question is: I want the cin and cout to work in the c program. I have included the following libraries

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <linux/types.h>
    #include <asm/types.h>
    #include <linux/socket.h>
    #include <asm/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <errno.h>
```

and for the cin and cout to work I used the iostream library in c++ which does not work in c. Kindly advise me of any library I can use or probably if I can convert the code to work in c programming.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are in the c++ header `iostream` which is written in c++. While valid c is (typically) valid c++, this relationship doesn't work in reverse--`cin` and `cout` can't be used in a c program.

Comment: iostreams won't work in C, you'll have to use `printf()`

Comment: Hmm thanks I will try that now

Comment: @Joshua: "While valid c is (typically) valid c++," That is (typically) wrong. There are some semantic differences and some syntaxtical. Just think of casting `void *`.

Comment: If you use C++ features, you do **not** have C code anymore! Even if the syntax is identical, semantics might differ.

Comment: @Olaf in what way was my statement wrong? I made sure to state that C code isn't always valid C++ code. As far as I can tell, the fact that there are *some* instances where C doesn't convert well to C++, but that it does so in many cases, means that C is typically valid C++. In fact, as I recall, the ability to interpret C code is one of the driving factors behind C++ being 'built' on C.

Comment: @jaggedSpire and everyone else thanks for the comment and advise I have solved the problem

Comment: "in many cases, means that C is typically valid C++" only for trivial programs. Once you use `malloc` & friends, it should actually be **not**. (hint: it is not primarily because of `malloc` as such. And using a C programming style in C++ is complete nonsense (again: for non-trivial code).

Comment: @Olaf Because the common idiom for dynamically allocating memory via `malloc` in C uses an cast that has been been rendered illegal in C++, and proper conversion would have that cast be made explicit?

Comment: @jaggedSpire: True for the first part, false for the latter. Explictly casting might shadow type errors, as the compiler must not warn anymore. However, have a cookie:-)

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for the clarification, and the cookie. :-)

Comment: @Olaf "typical" doesn't mean "always"

Comment: I saw this question as a downvoted one but I vote it up because I get here due to this link https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/ Usually I give for granted the link is correct because it comes from an university but reading comments and answers here I conclude the link is not correct, cout is NOT part of C. Comments like @πάνταῥεῖ does are really useless, it's a waste of time read them, don't contribute to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

[`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and [`cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) are streams and do not exist in C.  You can use [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) and [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) in C.

In general running C code in C++ will work as C++ is based on C but going the other way can be problematic as there are a lot of features in C++ that don't exist in C.

Answer (score 1):

> any library i can use or probable if i can convert the code to work in
>   c programming

I think no such library or code conversion tools would exist.  Also, I believe you probably do not want such a thing.

IMHO, C and C++ are two languages, so you will be required to keep the compilation units separate based on code type:

1a) It is (mostly true) that C functions can only be compiled in a C compilation unit.

1b) A C compilation unit can not compile or understand C++.

2a) C++ functions or methods can only be compiled in a C++ compilation unit.

2b) A C++ compilation unit *CAN* produce C link-able function, but as said in other answers, C and C++ do not necessarily generate identical code for the same 'c-style' function.

The issue (of 1 and 2 above) is sometimes called (or used to be called?) name mangling, specifically what the linker uses to connect the code of different compilation units.  C++ uses name mangling, C does not.

3) It is trivial to call C functions (defined and compiled in a C compilation unit) from C++ code (in a C++ compilation unit) ... use 'extern "C" '.  The extern "C" causes the C++ compiler to generate the function call with an unmangled link name, a name that C code can link to and invoke.

4) It is fairly easy (though possibly not trivial) to call C++ functions (defined in a C++ compilation unit) from code in a C compilation unit.

But one 'direct' approach is to provide in the C++ compilation unit a C style function interface declared with the request to not mangle the name.

4a) within the C++ code, declare and implement a C function (i.e. foo()) with the extern "C" declaration.  This function, though c-style, is able to access or perform the desired C++ function.

4b) The extern "C" foo() can be invoked from the code of a C compilation unit (note: where there is no extern "C").

4c) the Linker will connect the unmangled name of foo() ... thus supporting the C code invocation of the C++ function foo().

5) It is somewhat more challenging to invoke a class method from a C function, because the C++ class method will typically require a specific instance through which to address the object.  And C code knows little about class instances.

With enough pieces, it can be done. For instance, I have used a static class methods to connect interrupts (always C or assy code) to a C++ object instance.  But without compelling reasons (like interrupt handling), I choose to write using C++.